# Python doesn't program does not end

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I can get my loop to work successfully, but when i type in the word, end, my code will not exit. Whats going on?

```
word = ("end")

while word != True:
    x= input("enter a word: ")
    reverse = (x[::-1])
    print(reverse)

print("Done")
```

Comment: You are not assigning anything to `word` in your loop. There's no mechanism to ever make the the condition `word != True` false.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some implementation. But here's the fixed code.

```py
word = "end"

 while True:
    x = input("enter a word: ")
    if x == word:
        break

    reverse = (x[::-1])
    print(reverse)
print("done")
```

```py
enter a word: asd
dsa
enter a word: ds
sd
enter a word: asd
dsa
enter a word: ewq
qwe
enter a word: end
done
>>>
```

Notes:

1. The code will loop until `break` has been executed.
2. We have to declare where to stop, so we added a conditional before reversing the word.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't changing the value of word so it goes on forever.
what I would do:

```
word = 'false'
while word != "end":
    word= input("enter a word: ")
    reverse = (word[::-1])
    print(reverse)
print("done")
```

and inputs return strings, so its a thing to keep in mind

Comment: How do i change the value of my variable, "word", if I've already made it not to be true?

Comment: like that above

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants to type the word `end` to exit the loop. It's not clear if they want to print `'dne'` in the final instance.

Comment: Yeah i appreciate it. I dont want end to exit the final instance, but idk ‍♂️. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: Probably more pythonic to initialise `word` to `None` rather than the string `'false'` which could also be a valid input...

Answer (score 0):

You've used the while loop as `while word!=True`. You are not changing the string word here. Hence, the condition is True ever. Remove the while loop and execute your code as :

```
word = 0
x= input("enter a word: ")
reverse = (x[::-1])
print(reverse)
print("Done")
```